# One last question concerning callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
const geocode = (address, callback) => {
  const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${address}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVya3VyMTIzIiwiYSI6ImNrYjVndDk3bjBvNGEyeW16cHlid2txZ3YifQ.NGOWOq0yq0wvkhzDzjnUpQ&limit=1`;
  request({ url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
    const data = response.body;
    if (error) {
      callback('Unable to connect to the Geo API', null);
    } else if (data.message === 'Not Found' || data.features.length === 0) {
      callback('Location not found', null);
    } else {
      callback(null, {
        longitude: data.features[0].center[0],
        latitude: data.features[0].center[1],
        location: data.features[0].place_name,
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Hey guys, I have got one last question concerning callback functions. In the code above, the callback function is called as soon as the web API finishes, but why does this work and not a return statement instead of the callback function, like:

```
return {
        longitude: data.features[0].center[0],
        latitude: data.features[0].center[1],
        location: data.features[0].place_name,
      }
```

So why is the callback function only called when the WEB API finishes but the return function gets called immediatly and thus doesn't work, but why actually? Isn't return not also something like a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is *Where is it supposed to return to?*. In your case, you are inside a callback that get's called by `request`s inner logic, so you can return to that logic (however that will be useless). A function always runs synchronously, which also means you have to return synchronously. You cannot return after the function finished executing:

```
 function synchronous(asynchronous) {
    setTimeout(function callback () {
       var value = asynchronous(); // This is the place were the value ends up ...
    }, 1000);
    return; // however we can't return value here as this part executed long before
 }

 synchronous(function callback2() {
   return "test"; // this will end up in 'value'
 });
```

The code will basically have the following tasks and callstacks:

```
 task: synchronous execution
   -> synchronous() -> setTimeout()
   <-               <-               // this is the place you want to return to   

 task: timer done
   -> callback() -> callback2()
   <-            <-              // this is the place were you actually return
```

Comment: But how does the program now that it should execute the callback function only when the API is finished? Kannst auch auf Deutsch antworten, vielleicht wird es mir dann klar...

Comment: Well at some point, you call a browser API (such as `setTimeout`, or others for networking). You do pass a function to that API (if it's asynchronous). The API will then store the function somewhere, and will start the asynchronous action (setting a timer, ...). Then when that action occurs (the timer is done, ...), it'll take the stored function and the arguments meant to be passed to it, and create a *task* (or *event*) out of it. This will then end up in a task queue (read: event loop), and at some point the engine picks it up, and calls the function with the arguments.

Comment: Ich antworte dir auch gerne auf deutsch, aber eigentlich sollen Antworten und Kommentare ja allen zu Gute kommen, deshalb würde ich Englisch bevorzugen :)

Comment: So return is indeed not possible because it doesn't satisfies the properties of a function, did I get this right?

Comment: Well, you can `return`, the value just doesn't end up where you want it to. When you `return`, you basically tell the engine to go up in the call stack. In your case, the function below in the callstack will be some `request` inner handler. There is no way to return to the `geocode` function, cause that function was part of another task, and was on another callstack. The function is long gone.

Comment: I actually read a lot of documentation now and the answer is, that return would work if just the function we want to use the return would wait long enough, so it does actually return something to the geocode function but just way too late and, thus, we can for example use callback functions in ordre to solve this problem.